# How to check if a string contains certain characters

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to make a script that checks if a string contains a certain character. This is what I have tried:

```
$disallowedChars = array('\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|');
if(in_array($string, $disallowedChars)) {
echo "String contains disallowed characters";
}
```

It returns this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ')'

I assume this is because `/`, `:`, `*`, and `?` are all operators. I don`t understand this, any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is bad logic, you can't use `in_array` for testing whole string against array of disallowed characters. Use `foreach` instead.

```
<?php

$strings = [
    'Good string.',
    'Bad : string.'
];

$disallowedChars = array('\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|');

// this foreach is just for looping over two strings
foreach ($strings as $str) {
    $clean = false;

    // here is the main point of your question, loop over all disallowed chars and check if char is in string (strpos)
    foreach ($disallowedChars as $dis) {
        if (strpos($str, $dis) !== FALSE) {
            $clean = true;
        }   
    }

    echo $clean ? 'String is OK' : 'String contain bad chars';
    echo '<br>';
    
    // for 'Good string.' returns 'String is OK'
    // for 'Bad : string.' returns 'String contain bad chars'
}
```

Comment: Wow, I am embarrassed that I didn't think of that. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The parser error is for this, you need to escape the backslash character '\' to '\\'

```
$disallowedChars = array('\\', '/', ':', '*', '?', '"', '<', '>', '|');
```

@pavel has right, inarray function don't check a string into string, is for check a value into array, to resolve your problem is more efficient to use regular expressions

[in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.in-array)

[PCRE Functions](https://www.php.net/manual/es/ref.pcre.php) for regex functions

```
$test = [
    'good string....'.
    'another string,,,',
    'bad maur\\fsdf',
    'bad dsfdsf:fgdf',
    'bad fdsd<fdsff',
    'bad dfdsfsdf>dfsf',
    'bad dfsdf|dfsdf',
];

$regex = '~[\\\\/\:\*\?"<>\|]~m';

foreach($test as $text) {
    if(preg_match($regex, $text)) {
        echo "{$text} contains disallowed characters\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right but it doesn't solve the main problem - it's in script logic and bad using of `in_array` function.